# NoSuchElementException in SBT dependent parser

Tags: scala, sbt

In an SBT plugin, I want to write a parser with tab completion that accepts and parses a function name and its parameters:

```
case class Param( name : String, tpe : String ) // tpe is for param type
case class Func( name : String, params : immutable.Seq[Param] )

def funcAndParamsParser( funcs : immutable.Set[Func] ) : Parser[(Func,immutable.Seq[String])] = ???
```

To implement this, I break it the problem into pieces:

```
def funcParser( funcs : immutable.Set[Func] ) : Parser[Func] = {
  val funcsByName = funcs.map( func => (func.name, func) ).toMap
  NotSpace.examples( funcsByName.keySet ).map( funcsByName )
}

def paramParser( param : Param ) : Parser[String] = {
  NotSpace.examples( s"<${param.name}, of type ${param.tpe}>" )
}

def paramsParser( params : immutable.Seq[Param] ) : Parser[immutable.Seq[String]] = {
  params.map( paramParser ).foldLeft( success( immutable.Seq.empty[String] ) ){
    (nascent, next) => nascent.flatMap( partial => Space ~> next.map( str => partial :+ str ) )
  }
}
```

Finally I can implement the main event:

```
def funcAndParamsParser( funcs : immutable.Set[Func] ) : Parser[(Func,immutable.Seq[String])] = {
  funcParser( funcs ).flatMap( func => paramsParser( func.params ).map( seq => ( func, seq ) ) )
}
```

All of the subsidiary parsers work fine, but the final combination, `funcAndParamsParser(...)`, fails with a `NoSuchElementException`.

```
val func0 = Func( "move", Param("x", "Int") :: Param("y", "Int") :: Nil )
val func1 = Func( "fill", Param("color", "Color") :: Nil )
val testParser = Space ~> funcAndParamsParser( immutable.Set( func0, func1 ) )
```

When I embed this parser in an `InputTask` that calls `testParser.parsed`, it sort of seems to work. Typing `<space>` then `<tab>` after the task name, I get the expected list of functions (although the example tab completion for the second argument to `move` is omitted).

```
> tmpTestDynamicParser 
fill <color, of type Color>   move <x, of type Int>
```

However, the parser always ultimately fails. If I type in what should be a valid input:

```
> tmpTestDynamicParser move 3 5
```

Or if I type a partial input and then tab:

```
> tmpTestDynamicParser mo
```

I get an inscrutable Exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: m
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
    at sbt.complete.Parser$Value.map(Parser.scala:161)
    at sbt.complete.MapParser.resultEmpty$lzycompute(Parser.scala:704)
    at sbt.complete.MapParser.resultEmpty(Parser.scala:704)
    at sbt.complete.BindParser.derive(Parser.scala:694)
    at sbt.complete.MapParser.derive(Parser.scala:705)
    at sbt.complete.MapParser.derive(Parser.scala:705)
    at sbt.complete.MapParser.derive(Parser.scala:705)
    at sbt.complete.MapParser.derive(Parser.scala:705)
    at sbt.complete.MapParser.derive(Parser.scala:705)
    at sbt.complete.ParserSeq$$anonfun$derive$6.apply(Parser.scala:676)
    at sbt.complete.ParserSeq$$anonfun$derive$6.apply(Parser.scala:676)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.complete.ParserSeq.derive(Parser.scala:676)
    at sbt.complete.MapParser.derive(Parser.scala:705)
    at sbt.complete.MapParser.derive(Parser.scala:705)
    at sbt.complete.ParserMain$class.derive1(Parser.scala:454)
    at sbt.complete.Parser$.derive1(Parser.scala:135)
    at sbt.complete.ParserMain$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Parser.scala:450)
    at sbt.complete.ParserMain$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Parser.scala:450)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.foldLeft(StringOps.scala:31)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:138)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.$div$colon(StringOps.scala:31)
    at sbt.complete.ParserMain$class.apply(Parser.scala:450)
    at sbt.complete.Parser$.apply(Parser.scala:135)
    at sbt.complete.ParserMain$class.completions(Parser.scala:464)
    at sbt.complete.Parser$.completions(Parser.scala:135)
    at sbt.complete.JLineCompletion$$anonfun$parserAsCompletor$1.apply(JLineCompletion.scala:52)
    at sbt.complete.JLineCompletion$$anonfun$parserAsCompletor$1.apply(JLineCompletion.scala:52)
    at sbt.complete.JLineCompletion$$anonfun$customCompletor$1$$anonfun$2.apply(JLineCompletion.scala:75)
    at sbt.complete.JLineCompletion$$anonfun$customCompletor$1$$anonfun$2.apply(JLineCompletion.scala:75)
    at sbt.complete.JLineCompletion$.complete(JLineCompletion.scala:94)
    at sbt.complete.JLineCompletion$$anonfun$customCompletor$1.apply(JLineCompletion.scala:75)
    at sbt.complete.JLineCompletion$$anonfun$customCompletor$1.apply(JLineCompletion.scala:74)
    at sbt.complete.JLineCompletion$CustomHandler.complete(JLineCompletion.scala:30)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.complete(ConsoleReader.java:3311)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2646)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2372)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2360)
    at sbt.JLine.sbt$JLine$$readLineDirectRaw(LineReader.scala:42)
    at sbt.JLine$$anonfun$readLineDirect$2.apply(LineReader.scala:34)
    at sbt.JLine$$anonfun$readLineDirect$2.apply(LineReader.scala:34)
    at sbt.Signals0.withHandler(Signal.scala:81)
    at sbt.Signals$.withHandler(Signal.scala:11)
    at sbt.JLine.readLineDirect(LineReader.scala:34)
    at sbt.JLine.readLineWithHistory(LineReader.scala:27)
    at sbt.JLine.sbt$JLine$$unsynchronizedReadLine(LineReader.scala:19)
    at sbt.JLine$$anonfun$readLine$1.apply(LineReader.scala:16)
    at sbt.JLine$$anonfun$readLine$1.apply(LineReader.scala:16)
    at sbt.JLine$$anonfun$withJLine$1.apply(LineReader.scala:117)
    at sbt.JLine$$anonfun$withJLine$1.apply(LineReader.scala:115)
    at sbt.JLine$.withTerminal(LineReader.scala:89)
    at sbt.JLine$.withJLine(LineReader.scala:115)
    at sbt.JLine.readLine(LineReader.scala:16)
    at sbt.BasicCommands$$anonfun$shell$1.apply(BasicCommands.scala:185)
    at sbt.BasicCommands$$anonfun$shell$1.apply(BasicCommands.scala:181)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:30)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$command$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Command.scala:30)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
^JException occurred while determining completions.
```

This seems like it should be a straightforward use-case for SBT parsers, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix the mysterious Exception, and generally make things work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So, I'm an idiot.

The problem was here:

```
def funcParser( funcs : immutable.Set[Func] ) : Parser[Func] = {
  val funcsByName = funcs.map( func => (func.name, func) ).toMap
  NotSpace.examples( funcsByName.keySet ).map( funcsByName )
}
```

`NotSpace` can yield a successful, valid result for items not contained in the keys to `funcsByName`, provoking a `NoSuchElementException` when that result is used as a key to that `Map`. The solution was to use a series of literal Parsers chained together with `|`:

```
def funcParser( funcs : immutable.Set[Func] ) : Parser[Func] = {
  val funcsByName = funcs.map( func => (func.name, func) ).toMap
  val baseParser = funcsByName.keySet.foldLeft( failure("not a function name") : Parser[String] )( ( nascent, next ) => nascent | literal( next ) )
  baseParser.map( processedNamesToFunctions )
}
```